# How to compare two nested lists?

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have two nested lists. Both lists are quite similar, they are different versions of the same file written on top of each other.

The list structure looks like `list = [[name, version, id],[name, version, id], ...]`

```
list_1 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.5','32fv423'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2','eelp234']] 

list_2 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.6','3254323'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-newss','v1.0.2','eelp234']]
```

I want to iterate and compare if the names in `list_1` exist in the `list_2`, and if it does, if the version of that component in `list_1` is not equal to version of the component in `list_2` (if there is a version upgrade of a library), then print the `newlist_1 = [name, old version, new version, old id, new id]` for all unique cases.

If there is a name in `list_1`, which does not exist in `list_2`, meaning a library is deprecated, in that case, a new output list should contain `newlist_2 = [name, old version, 'deprecated', old id, 'deprecated']`.

If there is a name in `list_2`, which does not exist in `list_1`, meaning a library is newly added, in that case, a new output list should contain `newlist_3 = [name, 'new', new version, new, new id]`.

The final output should be 3 lists and should get:

```
newlist_1 = ['mipl-avfd', 'v1.1.5', 'v1.1.6','32fv423', '3254323']
newlist_2 = ['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2', 'deprecated','eelp234', 'deprecated']
newlist_3 = ['mipl-newss', 'new','v1.0.2','new', 'eelp234']
```

I tried to write something like:

```
for items in list_1:
    for item in list_2: 
        if item[0] == items[0] and item[1] != items[1]:
             list_difference = [item[0], items[1], item[1], items[2], items[2]]
             newlist_1.append(list_difference)
        elif item[0] not in items[0]: 
             list_old_param = [item[0], item[1], 'deprecated', items[2], 'not-exist']
             newlist_2.append(list_old_param)
        elif items[0] not in item[0]:
             list_new_param = [item[0], 'new' , items[1], 'new', items[2]]
             newlist_3.append(list_new_param)
```

All data seems to append and create multiple entries because of the two `for` loops, so how do I comprehend lists?

Questions : How to make it work with appending only unique entries? What are some smart ways to write code to compare such two lists? What are the simplest ways? how to ensure the loops do not overfit these lists as the lists would keep on changing?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to run through each list in turn looking for names in the other list. You can get direct access by using two `dict`s.

My function below prepares the data by converting the lists to dicts and running through each `dict` and attempting to access the name in the other.

```py
list_1 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.5','32fv423'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-oldss','v1.0.2','eelp234']] 


list_2 = [
['mipl-abnd','v1.0.2','eelp234'],
['mipl-avfd','v1.1.6','3254323'],
['mipl-awsd','v9.0.2','234eelp'],
['mipl-tgfd','v3.0.0','124fdge'],
['mipl-hrdss','v1.0.2','543rfd3'],
['mipl-newss','v1.0.2','eelp234']]

def compareLists(l1, l2):
    d1 = {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in l1}
    d2 = {k:[v1,v2] for k,v1,v2 in l2}
    result = []
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k in d1:
            v1 = d1[k]
            if v1[0] != v[0]:
                result.append([k,v1[0],v[0], v1[1],v[1]])
        else:
            result.append([k,'new',v[0],'new', v[1]])

    for k,v in d1.items():
        if k not in d2:
            result.append([k,v[0],'deprecated', v[1], 'deprecated'])
    
    return result

r = compareLists(list_1,list_2)
for d in r:
    print(d)
```

Output as required.

Comment: Thank you, that does the job. I've never played with both lists and dicts together.